# loss function in tensorflow, error: Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am doing a regression problem using 3 layers of neural networks in tensorflow. In the implementation of MSE loss function, I use two methods. First: I directly call

```
error = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=true_value, predictions=predicted_value, weights=1);
```

Second: I mannual implement it as

```
error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(true_value, predicted_value))
```

Since I evaluate the test error in real time by loading all test data into the model for prediction, the first method always give me the error

> Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)

after several hundreds of epochs, while the second one works well.

It seems the error comes from out-of-memory issue, I am wondering what is the difference between these two methods? Aren't they equivalent?

Comment: After posting this question, I come to the same problem when using the second method after 2000 epochs. So is it recommended to record test loss periodically during training? It seems this recording slows down the trainning process and caused memory problems.

Comment: If the error is due to you running out of memory, You should probably find and fix the memory issue. I don't see how "record test loss periodically during training" can help you with a memory problem.